# Using Regular Expression Match Type in Google Analytics to track my changing date URL a trackable goal

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I would like to track a URL destination goal type in Google Analytics using a Regular Expression Match type.

I have a URL that is generated with a unique date that I want to setup as a goal.

Can someone help me verify what I'm doing wrong with the strings? I cannot get this to work in GA. Thank you.

Generated URL:

```
 /products/usedleadestimator.aspx?ckSRC=030712success
```

Goal Tracking URL in Google Analytics W/ RegEx:

```
^/products/usedleadestimator\.aspx\?ckSRC=\[^/]*\success
```

Generated URL:

```
/products/newleadestimator.aspx?ckSRC=040712success
```

Goal Tracking URL in Google Analytics W/ RegEx:

```
^/products/newleadestimator\.aspx\?ckSRC=\[^/]*\success
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how GA's 'goal tracking' works, but I believe the regular expression you're looking for is:

```
^/products/usedleadestimator\.aspx\?ckSRC=\d+success$
```

In your pattern, you had `\success`, which would have been interepreted as trying to match a space character followed by 'uccess'. I'm not sure why the slash was there in the first place!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped - please accept the answer using the tick next to the question :)